# What do large times spent in Thread#initialize and Thread#join mean in JRuby profiling?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, profiling, jruby

I'm trying to profile an application using JRuby's built-in profiler.

Most of the time is taken in `ClassIsOfInterest.method_that_is_of_interest`, which in turn has most of its time taken in `Thread#initialize` and `Thread#join`

```
     total        self    children       calls  method
----------------------------------------------------------------
     31.36        0.02       31.35        4525  Array#each
     31.06        0.00       31.06           2  Test::Unit::RunCount.run_once
     31.06        0.00       31.06           1  Test::Unit::RunCount.run
     31.06        0.00       31.06           1  MiniTest::Unit#run
     31.06        0.00       31.05           1  MiniTest::Unit#_run
     31.01        0.00       31.01        2219  Kernel.send
     31.00        0.00       31.00           1  MiniTest::Unit#run_tests
     31.00        0.00       31.00           1  MiniTest::Unit#_run_anything
     30.99        0.00       30.99           1  Test::Unit::Runner#_run_suites
     30.99        0.00       30.99           5  MiniTest::Unit#_run_suite
     30.99        0.00       30.98       21629  Array#map
     30.98        0.00       30.98           1  Test::Unit::TestCase#run
     30.98        0.00       30.98           1  MiniTest::Unit::TestCase#run
     30.98        0.00       30.98         659  BasicObject#__send__
     30.98        0.00       30.98           1  MyTestClass#my_test_method
     30.80        0.00       30.80          18  Enumerable.each_with_index
     30.77        0.00       30.77          15  MyTestHelper.generate_call_parser_based_on_barcoded_sequence
     30.26        0.00       30.25        4943  Class#new_proxy
     26.13        0.00       26.13          15  MyProductionClass1#my_production_method1

<snip boring methods with zero self time>

     24.27        0.00       24.27          15  ClassIsOfInterest.method_that_is_of_interest
     13.71        0.01       13.71         541  Enumerable.map
     13.48        0.86       12.63          30  Range#each
     12.62        0.22       12.41         450  Thread.new
     12.41       12.41        0.00         450  Thread#initialize
     10.78       10.78        0.00         450  Thread#join
      4.03        0.12        3.91         539  Kernel.require
      3.34        0.00        3.34         248  Kernel.require
      2.49        0.00        2.49          15  MyTestFixture.create_fixture

<snip boring methods with small total times>
```

Each invocation of `ClassIsOfInterest.method_that_is_of_interest` is creating 30 threads, which is probably overkill, but I assume it shouldn't degrade performance that much. When I only had three threads created per invocation, I got

```
 23.16        0.00       23.15          15  ClassIsOfInterest.method_that_is_of_interest
 22.73       22.73        0.00          45  Thread#join
  4.18        0.08        4.10         539  Kernel.require
  3.56        0.00        3.56         248  Kernel.require
  2.78        0.00        2.78          15  MyTestFixture.create_fixture
```

Do large time values for `Thread#initialize` (in the first profile) and `Thread#join` indicate that the code responsible for threading is taking a while, or merely that the code that is executed within the thread is taking a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see `Thread#join` is that your main thread is spending lots of time waiting for the other threads to finish. Most of the time spent in `method_that_is_of_interest` is spent blocking on `Thread#join` because it's not doing any other work. I wouldn't worry too much about it -- the profile is just saying that one of your threads is blocking on what other threads are doing. A better performance measurement in this case is the total running time, run the code with different numbers of threads and see where the sweet spot is.

The reason why `Thread.new`/`Thread#initialize` shows up is that threads are expensive objects to create. If you're calling this method often and it creates all those threads every time I suggest you look into Java's [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) API. Create a thread pool with `Executors` once (when your application starts up) and submit all the tasks to the pool instead of creating new threads (you can use [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) to wait for all tasks to complete, or just call `#get` on the `FutureTask` instances you get when you submit your tasks).